# CentOS Mondo Rescue Error to Restore the iso: Kernel Panic

Tags: centos, kernel, backup, system, iso

I am trying to create an image (.iso) of my installed CentOS 5.11 system, for this i am using the "Mondo Rescue" with the command:

`mondoarchive -Oi -9 -L -d /tmp/centos_iso -I / -T /tmp/centos_iso -p centos_image -s 4480m -E "/tmp|/var/spool/squid|/var/log"`

The image is generated, and apparently is functional.

To install the iso in other machine i'm using the option "Nuke", in initialization page of "Mondo Rescue", like is represented in below image

[image: Mondo Restore Page]

When attempting to perform the installation, the following error occurs during the process:

`Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init= options to kernel.`